# Calculating this integral? $\int \frac{1}{1+x^2\cdot y^2}$dy

Tags: integration

So I have this integral $\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{1+x^2\cdot y^2}dy$. Is it possible to rewrite this integral to $\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{1+u^2}du$ using substitution, as I know the value of this integral, that is I want to remove $x^2$ from the denominator somehow. I'm not sure how.

Comment: Btw, the limits on these integrals are $-\infty$ and $\infty$.

Comment: Since you are only integrating with respect to $y$ you may treat $x^2$ like a constant. When you realize this it is easy to recognize this integral as a standard one.

Comment: @seht111, then you should write $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ instead of just $\int$. You can still edit you post

Answer (score 2):

Setting $$xy=t$$ then we get $$xdy=dt$$ and our integral will be
$$\frac{1}{x}\int\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  \int \frac{1}{1+x^2 y^2} \, dy
  &= \frac1{x^2} \int \frac{1}{\frac1{x^2}+y^2} \, dy \\
  &= \frac1{x^2} \int \frac{1}{\left( \frac1{x} \right)^2+y^2} \, dy \\
  &= \frac1{x^2} \cdot \frac1{\frac1{x}} \cdot \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{\frac1{x}} + C \\
  &= \frac1{x} \tan^{-1} xy + C
\end{align*}